# Add a custom new language package Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, module, language, package

I'm trying to create a new language package for Magento 2.1.3.

I've been following this [guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack) but without success.


I tried the following steps without success:


**1) *Collect phrases from your module***

```
magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/sv_SE.csv" -m
```

**2) *Translate the words and phrases***

I translated some words to Swedish.


**3) *Create the language package***

```
magento i18n:pack /var/www/html/magento2/sv_SE.csv -d sv_SE
```

**4) *Create a directory for the language package***

I created a directory named **i18n**, **DSE** and another directory named **sv_se**.

```
/var/www/html/magento2/app/i18n/DSE/sv_se
```

**5) *In the above directory, I added the following:***

- composer.json
- registration.php
- language.xml

My `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "dse/language-sv_se",
    "description": "Swedish language",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-language",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

My `registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'magento_sv_se',
    __DIR__
);
```

My `language.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Languag$
    <code>sv_SE</code>
    <vendor>dse</vendor>
    <package>sv_se</package>
</language>
```

What am I missing? 

The phrases that I entered in `sv_SE.csv` before I ran `magento i18n:pack` are not showing up on my site.

All commands ran with success (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

**I forgot to flush the cache...**

In admin CP, go to `System` -> `Cache Management`

Click `Flush Magento Cache`, and click `Flush Static Files Cache`

Now it works! :)