# Magento 2 mongolian language

Tags: magento2, localisation, language, locale

We setup the multilanguage websites. I'm trying to setup the website for Mongolian Country. In default magento missing the mongolian Locale language. How to add this language in locale.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom language package you need to do few things.

1. Collect and translate words and phrases.
2. Run the language package command.
3. Create directories and files.
4. (Optional.) Configure multiple packages for a language.

Dev docs will be your best guide for this. Here is a link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack

See also, this thread: [Add a custom new language package Magento 2.1.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155005/add-a-custom-new-language-package-magento-2-1-3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of locale which nginx supported:

```
Array
(
[0] => af
[1] => af_NA
[2] => af_ZA
[3] => agq
[4] => agq_CM
[5] => ak
[6] => ak_GH
[7] => am
[8] => am_ET
[9] => ar
[10] => ar_001
[11] => ar_AE
[12] => ar_BH
[13] => ar_DJ
[14] => ar_DZ
[15] => ar_EG
[16] => ar_EH
[17] => ar_ER
[18] => ar_IL
[19] => ar_IQ
[20] => ar_JO
[21] => ar_KM
[22] => ar_KW
[23] => ar_LB
[24] => ar_LY
[25] => ar_MA
[26] => ar_MR
[27] => ar_OM
[28] => ar_PS
[29] => ar_QA
[30] => ar_SA
[31] => ar_SD
[32] => ar_SO
[33] => ar_SY
[34] => ar_TD
[35] => ar_TN
[36] => ar_YE
[37] => as
[38] => as_IN
[39] => asa
[40] => asa_TZ
[41] => az
[42] => az_Cyrl
[43] => az_Cyrl_AZ
[44] => az_Latn
[45] => az_Latn_AZ
[46] => bas
[47] => bas_CM
[48] => be
[49] => be_BY
[50] => bem
[51] => bem_ZM
[52] => bez
[53] => bez_TZ
[54] => bg
[55] => bg_BG
[56] => bm
[57] => bm_ML
[58] => bn
[59] => bn_BD
[60] => bn_IN
[61] => bo
[62] => bo_CN
[63] => bo_IN
[64] => br
[65] => br_FR
[66] => brx
[67] => brx_IN
[68] => bs
[69] => bs_Cyrl
[70] => bs_Cyrl_BA
[71] => bs_Latn
[72] => bs_Latn_BA
[73] => ca
[74] => ca_AD
[75] => ca_ES
[76] => cgg
[77] => cgg_UG
[78] => chr
[79] => chr_US
[80] => cs
[81] => cs_CZ
[82] => cy
[83] => cy_GB
[84] => da
[85] => da_DK
[86] => dav
[87] => dav_KE
[88] => de
[89] => de_AT
[90] => de_BE
[91] => de_CH
[92] => de_DE
[93] => de_LI
[94] => de_LU
[95] => dje
[96] => dje_NE
[97] => dua
[98] => dua_CM
[99] => dyo
[100] => dyo_SN
[101] => dz
[102] => dz_BT
[103] => ebu
[104] => ebu_KE
[105] => ee
[106] => ee_GH
[107] => ee_TG
[108] => el
[109] => el_CY
[110] => el_GR
[111] => en
[112] => en_150
[113] => en_AG
[114] => en_AS
[115] => en_AU
[116] => en_BB
[117] => en_BE
[118] => en_BM
[119] => en_BS
[120] => en_BW
[121] => en_BZ
[122] => en_CA
[123] => en_CM
[124] => en_DM
[125] => en_FJ
[126] => en_FM
[127] => en_GB
[128] => en_GD
[129] => en_GG
[130] => en_GH
[131] => en_GI
[132] => en_GM
[133] => en_GU
[134] => en_GY
[135] => en_HK
[136] => en_IE
[137] => en_IM
[138] => en_IN
[139] => en_JE
[140] => en_JM
[141] => en_KE
[142] => en_KI
[143] => en_KN
[144] => en_KY
[145] => en_LC
[146] => en_LR
[147] => en_LS
[148] => en_MG
[149] => en_MH
[150] => en_MP
[151] => en_MT
[152] => en_MU
[153] => en_MW
[154] => en_NA
[155] => en_NG
[156] => en_NZ
[157] => en_PG
[158] => en_PH
[159] => en_PK
[160] => en_PR
[161] => en_PW
[162] => en_SB
[163] => en_SC
[164] => en_SG
[165] => en_SL
[166] => en_SS
[167] => en_SZ
[168] => en_TC
[169] => en_TO
[170] => en_TT
[171] => en_TZ
[172] => en_UG
[173] => en_UM
[174] => en_US
[175] => en_US_POSIX
[176] => en_VC
[177] => en_VG
[178] => en_VI
[179] => en_VU
[180] => en_WS
[181] => en_ZA
[182] => en_ZM
[183] => en_ZW
[184] => eo
[185] => es
[186] => es_419
[187] => es_AR
[188] => es_BO
[189] => es_CL
[190] => es_CO
[191] => es_CR
[192] => es_CU
[193] => es_DO
[194] => es_EA
[195] => es_EC
[196] => es_ES
[197] => es_GQ
[198] => es_GT
[199] => es_HN
[200] => es_IC
[201] => es_MX
[202] => es_NI
[203] => es_PA
[204] => es_PE
[205] => es_PH
[206] => es_PR
[207] => es_PY
[208] => es_SV
[209] => es_US
[210] => es_UY
[211] => es_VE
[212] => et
[213] => et_EE
[214] => eu
[215] => eu_ES
[216] => ewo
[217] => ewo_CM
[218] => fa
[219] => fa_AF
[220] => fa_IR
[221] => ff
[222] => ff_SN
[223] => fi
[224] => fi_FI
[225] => fil
[226] => fil_PH
[227] => fo
[228] => fo_FO
[229] => fr
[230] => fr_BE
[231] => fr_BF
[232] => fr_BI
[233] => fr_BJ
[234] => fr_BL
[235] => fr_CA
[236] => fr_CD
[237] => fr_CF
[238] => fr_CG
[239] => fr_CH
[240] => fr_CI
[241] => fr_CM
[242] => fr_DJ
[243] => fr_DZ
[244] => fr_FR
[245] => fr_GA
[246] => fr_GF
[247] => fr_GN
[248] => fr_GP
[249] => fr_GQ
[250] => fr_HT
[251] => fr_KM
[252] => fr_LU
[253] => fr_MA
[254] => fr_MC
[255] => fr_MF
[256] => fr_MG
[257] => fr_ML
[258] => fr_MQ
[259] => fr_MR
[260] => fr_MU
[261] => fr_NC
[262] => fr_NE
[263] => fr_PF
[264] => fr_RE
[265] => fr_RW
[266] => fr_SC
[267] => fr_SN
[268] => fr_SY
[269] => fr_TD
[270] => fr_TG
[271] => fr_TN
[272] => fr_VU
[273] => fr_YT
[274] => ga
[275] => ga_IE
[276] => gl
[277] => gl_ES
[278] => gsw
[279] => gsw_CH
[280] => gu
[281] => gu_IN
[282] => guz
[283] => guz_KE
[284] => gv
[285] => gv_GB
[286] => ha
[287] => ha_Latn
[288] => ha_Latn_GH
[289] => ha_Latn_NE
[290] => ha_Latn_NG
[291] => haw
[292] => haw_US
[293] => he
[294] => he_IL
[295] => hi
[296] => hi_IN
[297] => hr
[298] => hr_BA
[299] => hr_HR
[300] => hu
[301] => hu_HU
[302] => hy
[303] => hy_AM
[304] => id
[305] => id_ID
[306] => ig
[307] => ig_NG
[308] => ii
[309] => ii_CN
[310] => is
[311] => is_IS
[312] => it
[313] => it_CH
[314] => it_IT
[315] => it_SM
[316] => ja
[317] => ja_JP
[318] => jgo
[319] => jgo_CM
[320] => jmc
[321] => jmc_TZ
[322] => ka
[323] => ka_GE
[324] => kab
[325] => kab_DZ
[326] => kam
[327] => kam_KE
[328] => kde
[329] => kde_TZ
[330] => kea
[331] => kea_CV
[332] => khq
[333] => khq_ML
[334] => ki
[335] => ki_KE
[336] => kk
[337] => kk_Cyrl
[338] => kk_Cyrl_KZ
[339] => kl
[340] => kl_GL
[341] => kln
[342] => kln_KE
[343] => km
[344] => km_KH
[345] => kn
[346] => kn_IN
[347] => ko
[348] => ko_KP
[349] => ko_KR
[350] => kok
[351] => kok_IN
[352] => ks
[353] => ks_Arab
[354] => ks_Arab_IN
[355] => ksb
[356] => ksb_TZ
[357] => ksf
[358] => ksf_CM
[359] => kw
[360] => kw_GB
[361] => lag
[362] => lag_TZ
[363] => lg
[364] => lg_UG
[365] => ln
[366] => ln_AO
[367] => ln_CD
[368] => ln_CF
[369] => ln_CG
[370] => lo
[371] => lo_LA
[372] => lt
[373] => lt_LT
[374] => lu
[375] => lu_CD
[376] => luo
[377] => luo_KE
[378] => luy
[379] => luy_KE
[380] => lv
[381] => lv_LV
[382] => mas
[383] => mas_KE
[384] => mas_TZ
[385] => mer
[386] => mer_KE
[387] => mfe
[388] => mfe_MU
[389] => mg
[390] => mg_MG
[391] => mgh
[392] => mgh_MZ
[393] => mgo
[394] => mgo_CM
[395] => mk
[396] => mk_MK
[397] => ml
[398] => ml_IN
[399] => mr
[400] => mr_IN
[401] => ms
[402] => ms_BN
[403] => ms_MY
[404] => ms_SG
[405] => mt
[406] => mt_MT
[407] => mua
[408] => mua_CM
[409] => my
[410] => my_MM
[411] => naq
[412] => naq_NA
[413] => nb
[414] => nb_NO
[415] => nd
[416] => nd_ZW
[417] => ne
[418] => ne_IN
[419] => ne_NP
[420] => nl
[421] => nl_AW
[422] => nl_BE
[423] => nl_CW
[424] => nl_NL
[425] => nl_SR
[426] => nl_SX
[427] => nmg
[428] => nmg_CM
[429] => nn
[430] => nn_NO
[431] => nus
[432] => nus_SD
[433] => nyn
[434] => nyn_UG
[435] => om
[436] => om_ET
[437] => om_KE
[438] => or
[439] => or_IN
[440] => pa
[441] => pa_Arab
[442] => pa_Arab_PK
[443] => pa_Guru
[444] => pa_Guru_IN
[445] => pl
[446] => pl_PL
[447] => ps
[448] => ps_AF
[449] => pt
[450] => pt_AO
[451] => pt_BR
[452] => pt_CV
[453] => pt_GW
[454] => pt_MO
[455] => pt_MZ
[456] => pt_PT
[457] => pt_ST
[458] => pt_TL
[459] => rm
[460] => rm_CH
[461] => rn
[462] => rn_BI
[463] => ro
[464] => ro_MD
[465] => ro_RO
[466] => rof
[467] => rof_TZ
[468] => ru
[469] => ru_BY
[470] => ru_KG
[471] => ru_KZ
[472] => ru_MD
[473] => ru_RU
[474] => ru_UA
[475] => rw
[476] => rw_RW
[477] => rwk
[478] => rwk_TZ
[479] => saq
[480] => saq_KE
[481] => sbp
[482] => sbp_TZ
[483] => seh
[484] => seh_MZ
[485] => ses
[486] => ses_ML
[487] => sg
[488] => sg_CF
[489] => shi
[490] => shi_Latn
[491] => shi_Latn_MA
[492] => shi_Tfng
[493] => shi_Tfng_MA
[494] => si
[495] => si_LK
[496] => sk
[497] => sk_SK
[498] => sl
[499] => sl_SI
[500] => sn
[501] => sn_ZW
[502] => so
[503] => so_DJ
[504] => so_ET
[505] => so_KE
[506] => so_SO
[507] => sq
[508] => sq_AL
[509] => sq_MK
[510] => sr
[511] => sr_Cyrl
[512] => sr_Cyrl_BA
[513] => sr_Cyrl_ME
[514] => sr_Cyrl_RS
[515] => sr_Latn
[516] => sr_Latn_BA
[517] => sr_Latn_ME
[518] => sr_Latn_RS
[519] => sv
[520] => sv_AX
[521] => sv_FI
[522] => sv_SE
[523] => sw
[524] => sw_KE
[525] => sw_TZ
[526] => sw_UG
[527] => swc
[528] => swc_CD
[529] => ta
[530] => ta_IN
[531] => ta_LK
[532] => ta_MY
[533] => ta_SG
[534] => te
[535] => te_IN
[536] => teo
[537] => teo_KE
[538] => teo_UG
[539] => th
[540] => th_TH
[541] => ti
[542] => ti_ER
[543] => ti_ET
[544] => to
[545] => to_TO
[546] => tr
[547] => tr_CY
[548] => tr_TR
[549] => twq
[550] => twq_NE
[551] => tzm
[552] => tzm_Latn
[553] => tzm_Latn_MA
[554] => uk
[555] => uk_UA
[556] => ur
[557] => ur_IN
[558] => ur_PK
[559] => uz
[560] => uz_Arab
[561] => uz_Arab_AF
[562] => uz_Cyrl
[563] => uz_Cyrl_UZ
[564] => uz_Latn
[565] => uz_Latn_UZ
[566] => vai
[567] => vai_Latn
[568] => vai_Latn_LR
[569] => vai_Vaii
[570] => vai_Vaii_LR
[571] => vi
[572] => vi_VN
[573] => vun
[574] => vun_TZ
[575] => xog
[576] => xog_UG
[577] => yav
[578] => yav_CM
[579] => yo
[580] => yo_NG
[581] => zh
[582] => zh_Hans
[583] => zh_Hans_CN
[584] => zh_Hans_HK
[585] => zh_Hans_MO
[586] => zh_Hans_SG
[587] => zh_Hant
[588] => zh_Hant_HK
[589] => zh_Hant_MO
[590] => zh_Hant_TW
[591] => zu
[592] => zu_ZA
)
```

From above, your locale **mn_Cyrl_MN** was not supported.
There are 2 ways to workaround:

1. Switch server to apache
2. You could use a never used locale as alternative, but not recommended. For example: **af_ZA**

   - Create an **af_ZA** package translation but the content is Mongolian
   - Select **Afrikaans (South Africa)** as locale for your store